# A puzzle on how Java implement volatile in new memory model (JSR 133)

Tags: java, concurrency, jvm, volatile

In [JSR 133 Java Memory Model FAQ](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#whatismm), it states

> the new memory model places stricter constraints on reordering of
>   volatile field accesses with other field accesses, volatile or not,
>   anything that was visible to thread A when it writes to volatile field
>   f becomes visible to thread B when it reads f

It also gives an example of how volatile fields can be used

```
class VolatileExample {
  int x = 0;
  volatile boolean v = false;

  public void writer() {
    x = 42;
    v = true;
  }

  public void reader() {
    if (v == true) {
      //uses x - guaranteed to see 42.
    }
  }
}
```

In the above code, the JVM (JIT?) would insert a `LoadLoad` memory barrier/fence between the load of `v` and the load of `x` in `reader()`, refers to [The JSR-133 Cookbook for Compiler Writers](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html) (the actual implementation depends on the underlying CPU architecture)

[image: barriers correspond to JSR-133 ordering rules]

and the hardwares use cache coherency protocol to ensure consistency between L1,2... cache and main memory.

But I guess these mechanisms seem to insufficient. In order to guaranteed to see `42` in `reader()`, does JVM (JIT) must read `v` (non-volatile) and `x` (volatile) from main memory (or L1,2.. cache which controlled by hardware) instead of CPU registers?

<strike>Is there any links or documents show the details of how JVM implement the new memory model? [The JSR-133 Cookbook for Compiler Writers](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html) only show how memory barriers are used, but say nothing about cache (in register, L1,2.. cache, main memory).</strike>

Comment: An interesting question, but asking for off site resources is explicitly off topic here!

Comment: you may be writing a Java compiler, but I'm not sure this is a Java question... maybe there are some better tags you could use related to cache management such as [tag:cpu-architecture] [tag:cpu-cache] ? [tag:assembly] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LoadLoad` barrier mentioned in JSR-133 Cookbook is not just some CPU instruction. It is a *logical* barrier which has impact on JIT compiler, too. In particular, it means that JIT compiler will not cache or reorder the load of `x` with respect to the load of `v`.

Comment: Thanks at first. I know that `LoadLoad` would be an no-op in some processor architectures, e.g. x86. And does `In particular, it means that JIT compiler will not cache` mean JIT compiler could not store or load x and v in or from CPU registers for optimization?

Comment: @Jacky JIT can do any optimization as long as it does not violate the spec. JVM can cache variables in registers, but not across the volatile load. So, volatile load serves as a barrier for such compiler optimizations.

Comment: Note that the some variables are provably not shared, like local variables. So they can be cached no matter what.

Comment: @curiousguy likewise, `final` variables might stay cached, if there's provenly no reflective modification in-between.

Comment: @Holger usually such fields are annotated with `@Stable`, unless they might have a default value, like `String::coder`

Comment: @Eugene that’s a very limited scope, as only JDK internal classes may have fields marked with that JDK implementation specific annotation. But in principle, every final field could stay cached through barriers.